# Как типизировать аргументы универсальной функции?

Tags: typescript, generics, типы

У меня есть объект с опциями, этот объект передается в универсальную функцию которая получает данные и диспатчит нужные экшены - делает сайд эффекты и т.д. Одно из полей этого объекта - это функция которая получает данные - в разных ситуациях эта функция разная, то есть в объекте с опциями мы предаем разные функции для получения разных данных.
Мне нужно типизировать аргументы этой функции под разные ситуации - аргуметы могут быть, могут не быть, это может быть объект с одним типом полей, может быть объект с другим типом полей - для этого я использую дженерики
Вот тип для объект с опциями:

```
type OptionsType<T, P> = {
  fetcher: (P) => Promise<T>; // <- вот интересующая функция
  fetcherParam?: P;
  fetchingStart: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
  fetchingFinish: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
  fill: FillActionType<T>;
  setErrorAction: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
};
```

так сделать не выходит

```
fetcher: (P) => Promise<T>
```

по идее можно сделать как-то так

```
fetcher: (params: P) => Promise<T>;
```

Но в таком случае если дженерик P у меня вот такого типа:

```
export type FeedsListRequestParamsType = {
  limit?: string;
  offset?: string;
};
```

А в качестве параметров в функция я передаю вот такой объект:

```
{ limit: "20", offset: "30" }
```

То я получаю ошибку о том, что { limit, offset, }: { limit?: string | undefined; offset?: string | undefined; } не асайнится с '(params?: FeedsListRequestParamsType | undefined) - на сколько я понимаю.
Не пойму, как типизировать функцию не указывая в типе **params**, то есть по смыслу вот так должно выглядеть:

```
fetcher: (P) => Promise<T>; //без **params**
```

но так синтаксически не верно. Не могу понять как описать это. То есть в параметры функции можно передать то, что будет  описано дженериком P

Answer (score 0):

песочница [там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiGBjYBLA9nKBeKBDBAKFElhQzgGEAnCPYdagHgBUA%20HfIk6AMVQA2A5GkwtwEVh1wEQhYhKgB5MKLgBncZFYAaKAAVpUAN6EoUAGYRgSABYRqALigAKMM-0BKHB33V0ALao6pLsANxQAPSRUEwAtFCATCCAfCCAQiBQgBwggLwgqYCsIIACILmAgiCAwiCAciCAkiCADCCA8iBQgCIgJVmAXCCAYiAZNWaW1nYO%20njUeAEA-B5hXVY2tqhwAOYAysADwM4iFDR0DMzwiOSYbOPmk3Yzs-xwwbare1S09IxMO2v7h5aCAs78Qs9wWqEHXRCwAAotR-NQftc1Bt7tsED8AQBfcaECAADzAjGAUB4UF4EAgABN1AAZYLAABKEAAjgBXCDqYD9QYBTSKXCmcwCVBBYCjKCM6inV7oCwWIH8wXCwjI%20SEiBIAQDaAANwGUHQqgo6mcKjUbO0sj0%20KJpPJVLpDKZAyGBogbHkmv1ADpjvZqC5jFBubznAAiABMAAY-XpReLrP6AMwhqCIzxAA)

```
type AnyAction = any
type ActionCreator<T> = any
type FillActionType<T> = any

type OptionsType<T, P> = {
  fetcher: (p: P) => Promise<T>; // <- вот интересующая функция
  fetcherParam?: P;
  fetchingStart: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
  fetchingFinish: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
  fill: FillActionType<T>;
  setErrorAction: ActionCreator<AnyAction>;
};

export type FeedsListRequestParamsType = {
  limit?: string;
  offset?: string;
};

declare var options: OptionsType<any, FeedsListRequestParamsType>

options.fetcher({ limit: "20", offset: "30" })
```

Comment: если что не ясно - пиши